# I don't understand how to use set_difference correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm

In the task it was said that it is necessary to get the "value" of the largest elements from the array. Then it should be compared with the second array, and duplicates should be excluded.

In the task it is necessary to use partial_sort_copy in vector, and set_difference.

The problem is that when you start the program crashes at all, even without showing what exactly the error is, that's why I am writing here

I looked at several sites with examples of using this function, but I used everything as there, and do not quite understand why it does not work and crashes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int value = 5;
    int A_ints[] { 1, 4, 12, 5, 1, 4, 6, 9, 0, 3 };
    vector<int> A_vec(value);
    vector<int> B_vec { 13, 12, 11, 10 };
    vector<int> C_vec;
    vector<int> D_vec {9, 6, 5, 4};


    partial_sort_copy(A_ints, A_ints + 9, A_vec.begin(), A_vec.end(), greater<int>());

    set_difference(A_vec.begin(), A_vec.end(), B_vec.begin(), B_vec.end(), C_vec.begin(), greater<int>());


    if (С_vec == D_vec)
         cout << "Success \n";
    else
         cout << "Failure \n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As a result, if set_difference will works correctly, then the last condition should return "Success".

Comment: Print out the results of each of those calls to the algorithm functions to see what you're working with.  You're probably being downvoted due to lack of research /  work.

Comment: Isn't the result only the number 12?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Also see [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) for details on how the function works.  You make several references to concepts or specifications that don't appear in your question, so we can't know exactly what you need to do, nor what you think you understand.  Your lack of debugging evidence makes it difficult to know what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior.  You're trying to stuff values into `C_vec`, when there is no room for those values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, partial_sort_copy works exactly right, I checked it before, he returns to me the vector {12, 9, 6, 5, 4}.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Oh, that's true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 5<sup>th</sup> argument to [`set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) is the parameter that the results of the algorithm will be written to.

You've passed in `C_vec.begin()` which is an iterator pointing to an *empty* vector. It's undefined behavior to write to an empty vector's iterator.

You have several issues here, but one solution for this particular problem would be to replace `C_vec.begin()` with an [`insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator):

```
inserter(C_vec, begin(C_vec))
```

Comment: I put in the fifth place what you suggested, but it highlights the "inserter" and gives me the error:
Missing instances of the "std :: inserter" function pattern matching the argument list.
#include <iterator> used

Comment: @InvalidDog So sorry, you'll need to use a non-constant iterator. I mistakenly wrote `cbegin` that should have been `begin` I've edited.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thank you very much. с:

Comment: Can you explain why the iterator used by the `std::inserter` is not invalidated when an insertion causes a reallocation in the vector ?

Comment: @fjardon The `insert_iterator`'s iterator member will be updated each time `insert` is called on it's container member. You can see a possible implementation of `insert_iterator` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/insert_iterator/?kw=insert_iterator Note the `insert_iterator`'s assignment operator implementation: `iter=container->insert(iter,std::move(value));` `++iter;` `return *this;`